# Coding a custom control like DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, datetimepicker

I've been trying to implement a custom control much like the standard Winform `DateTimePicker` control.. only that I need my control to display architectural length values in feet and inches.. like 9'-6".. the control should work in this way..

- A single up-down spin button should be visible on the right side of the control..
- The control should have 2 subfields, one for feet and one for inches.. the fields should **not** be individual `TextBox`es with their own borders..
- When no value has been associated with the control, it should display a ghost text string in grey color "Specify a length"..
- When the control is clicked it should display ?'-?", if the user clicks away without entering any length, the ghost text should be displayed again..
- Only the subfields should be selectable when clicked.. and the updown spin button only changes the currently selected subfield..
- The inches subfield should increment and decrement in units of 3, and wrap around its range of 0 to 11..

I think all of the functionality exist somewhere (or can be overridden) in the standard `DateTimePicker` control with the exception of ghost text requirement.. so probably what I should be asking is **how exactly does the `DateTimePicker` actually work? How can I replicate its appearance and behaviour..?**

I've looked around on Google and stackoverflow a lot but havent come across a similar question or answer..

---

EDIT 01:

I think a combination of updownbase and maskedtextbox might be what I need to work with.. but I have no idea how.. for one.. the maskedtextbox does not select subfields when clicked.. also how to get the updownbase to work with the currently selected subfield in the maskedtextbox..

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do and why you need to replicate behavior of DateTimePicker.

Comment: the imperial system measures lengths in feet and inches.. like 3.75 feet is written as 3'-9".. just like the datetimepicker shows date as 2012/11/24 00:00, and you can click on any subfield (year, month, date, hours or minutes) and use arrow keys to modify it.. im looking to code a control that displays 3'-9" where the feet and inches subfields (3 and 9) can be clicked and modified with arrow keys or spinbutton.. i thought it was clear in the question.. but if it still isnt i can elaborate upon it further.. =)

Comment: @AweSIM This is a very broad question as you have multiple requirements. The only answer I could see for it would be to write the control and explain every little piece. I think that is too big of a scope for the Question and Answer format of StackOverlow.

Comment: i think youre right.. it is too broad of a question.. ill try narrowing it down in a while.. =)

Comment: @AweSIM: you can try splitting one big issue into several questions and make sure each is 100% clear and can be easily answered.

Comment: i will from now on.. somehow i thought you should put all your questions in a single thread instead of scattering it around in small pieces.. but youre right.. modular approach would work better.. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to post some information which hopefully will help you get started, even though it does not directly address all of your concerns. First of all, you can get a free [dotpeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) decompiler, do CTRL+T, find `DateTimePicker` type and learn how it works. Be prepared to see a lot of winapi calls. Don't go this route unless you are confident that you will be able to comprehend everything and re-write it to work for your needs.

A more simple way would be to create a custom control. It may not look as nice, but at least you can get it working much faster. For example, create a `UserControl1`, which consists of a TextBox + a Button:

```
Public Class UserControl1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim frm As New Form2
    Dim p = frm.PointToScreen(New Point(Me.Left, Me.Bottom))
    frm.Location = New Point(Me.ParentForm.Left, Me.ParentForm.Top + 40) + p
    frm.Show()
  End Sub
End Class
```

**Disclaimer:** Doing +40 is a poor coding standard, but that's the best I could figure after struggling with conversion of coordinates to screen/client. If you find a better way - please suggest in comments.

Anyway, at design time it looks like this:

[image]

`Form2` is your popup, it will close if focus is lost, to imitate real popup behavior:

```
Public Class Form2
  Private Sub Form2_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Deactivate
    Me.Close()
  End Sub
End Class
```

At design time it looks like this ([FormBorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) = None):

[image]

Compile and drop this control onto your main form. Run your application - when you click the button, ft/in dropdown will appear underneath your control. Just as any popup would do (including that of `DateTimePicker`), it will disappear if you click anywhere else (`Deactivate` event is used to make it work like this). Here is a picture, to illustrate its behavior:

[image]

Now add validation, formatting etc.

Comment: that was a nice detailed answer mate.. =).. but i think you missed the point.. (as BenSwayne pointed out in his comment cuz the question has a broad scope).. im not looking for the drop down functionality.. i can live without that.. i was looking forward to understanding how the datetimepicker implements its subfields.. for instance when a date is displayed like "2012.11.24".. you can click on the "11" part and the "11" will get selected.. then you can use up down keys to increment or decrement the month.. same thing with the year and day subfields..

Comment: @AweSIM: sorry then - tried my best. Suggestion - create a new question, where you would describe just this part of your requirement. Also please include pictures with annotation, so that everything is 100% clear.